# Initializing a pointer array of objects

Tags: c++

So I have the following code

```
class UserDB
{
private:
AccountInfo* _accounts[200] ; // store up to 200 accounts
public:
UserDB();
virtual ~UserDB();
}
UserDB::UserDB(){
//code for initializing it to null
}
UserDB::~UserDB(){
    delete [] _accounts;
}
```

So basically I am trying to find this code to initialize `_accounts` to null but I cannot find a real answer, all the guides in the internet either say how to initialize an array, an object, or a pointer, but not something that is all three altogether, and even less how to initialize this kind of pointer to null, even whatever they are initializing [in the guides] looks very confusing, so I come once again to ask for help here.
Also, `AccountInfo` is just any random class.

Comment: I've seen this array of accounts three or four times already this week. I'm not sure if anyone already mentioned this to you, but you won't have an easy time trying to learn C++ without [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642). You can definitely learn by posing questions here on SO, but it certainly shouldn't be your sole source.

Comment: What is a good book anyway? All the ones I have ever put eyes on are most of the time incomplete and are not detailed enough.

Comment: Yokhen, @R.MartinhoFernandes provided a link to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) in his comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

you don't `delete[]` `_accounts` because the array is a *value* -- it is an array of pointers. IOW, its size is not equal to a pointer.

Here's a `std::vector` approach:

```
class UserDB {
private:
    std::vector<AccountInfo*> _accounts;
public:
    UserDB() : _accounts(200, 0) {}
    virtual ~UserDB() {}
};
```

However, you may prefer to use the vector's default initializer so you can use it to determine the number of accounts it holds.

**Update in response to comments below:**

Although there are reasons to hold an array of `AccountInfo*` pointers, you may also consider `std::vector` to hold an array of `AccountInfo`s *values*:

```
class UserDB {
private:
    std::vector<AccountInfo> _accounts;
public:
    UserDB() : _accounts() {}
    virtual ~UserDB() {}
    void appendAccountInfo(const AccountInfo& info) {
       this->_accounts.push_back(info);
    }
};
```

`std::vector` will handle all your allocation and reallocation needs for you. It's also nice because it's dynamically resizable, and you won't be constrained to a fixed number of `AccountInfos`.

Comment: I have no clue what vectors are whatsoever.

Comment: Also, if I shouldn't use 'delete' could you provide me an example of how would I dispose of the dynamic array in the destructor?

Comment: @Yokhen if you want to write (and be able to read) conventional c++, you will need to know what `std::vector` is. it is a replacement for a resizable c array and very very very very common in c++ programs. for array with a fixed size, you can use `std::array` instead. `std::vector` provides the `delete[]` and resizing implementations for you. since you are using pointers: it will *not* automatically `delete` each `AccountInfo` in the array (vector). You can use `std::vector<AccountInfo>` to hold an array of `AccountInfo`s by *value*.

Comment: @Yokhen: what dynamic array? There are no dynamic arrays in your code.

Comment: Well, the professor claimed that _accounts was a dynamic array. And yeah, sorry, I am researching as much as I can, but unfortunately I just started on C++ since 2 days ago.

Comment: @Yokhen no worries - there was a time I also thought "I have no clue what vectors are" =)

Answer (score 2):

create a constant instead of the magic number 200 (not really necessary but it makes the code more readable and safer when later changing)

```
const int numberOfAccounts = 200;

AccountInfo* _accounts[numberOfAccounts] 

UserDB::UserDB()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAccounts; ++i)
   {
     _accounts[i] = 0;
   }
}
```

now you have you 200 zeroed  pointers.

also have a habit of putting private members at the end of the class and public at the start,
especially by bigger classes you want to see the public stuff first, the private stuff you normally
don't want somebody to mess with.

```
class C
{
public:
protected:
private:
};
```

Comment: As a shortcut, instead of the for loop, you can do `UserDB::UserDB() : _accounts()`.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty neat and simpler :D

Answer (score 0):

I do remember having read that this would work:

```
UserDB():_accounts(){}
```

This should initialize the contents to `NULL`